# Exec running program on wrong computer?

Tags: java, exec, exe, runtime.exec

I have an .exe I want to run, but when I try running the exec code from another computer, it only runs it on the server computer. For example, I click on the link that that is suppose to run program.exe on my computer, but it ends up popping up and running on the server computer only.

Fyi, every machine that runs this code will have the program already installed.

```
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\program.exe");
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println(p.exitValue());
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I understand that it probably has something to do with exec sending commands to the server computer, but I'm still not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Where's this applet running? In-browser or in-server?

Comment: In browser, its on a website.

Comment: Looks like it's running in the right computer -- i.e., the computer you're telling it to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a signed Java applet that would run the exec code. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use psexec. PSEXEC by SYSInternals is great for remotely executing exe on a remote machine. You can put it in your c# code as well.

the syntax for psexec for running on remote pc is:

```
psexec \\ComputerName1 "\\unc_path\share\test.exe" -i
```

There are a bunch of parameters you can specify as well, such as interactive mode, and user accounts. -i is interactive btw.

Comment: Presuming that the server/machine are on the same network and windows networking isn't firewalled off somewhere...